# Table Doesn't Exist error when installing Vbulletin

Tags: vbulletin

This is what I see when i log in to AMember
after attempting to integrate the two.

> Vbulletin3 plugin error: DB - [] - incorrect value. Error: Table 'my_db.user' doesn't exist

I don't understand how to fix this error.
I know how to get to phpMyAdmin, but then
I don't what to do from there.  Can anyone
help?  Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you should be rereading online setup steps for vbulletin.  This really doesn't sound like a programming question - if you're not familiar with phpMyAdmin or databases in general, we're not going to be able to provide you a tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Have not used vbulletin before but looks like the table `my_db.user` is mising. Is this table is created by vbulletin then try running the setup again. If it is a custom table then make sure your connection string are correct and the table exists.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Setup of Vbulletin3 again! It seems that you didn't installed the tables of Vbulletin3.